# angularjs nodejs : best strategy for confidentiality / security?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, security

I am currently building a NodeJS / AngularJS (Ionic) app, and knowing that security is not my strong suit I set this topic aside for the time being (my app is still far from being public). Meaning that to this day, my app is a security disaster (the good news is: I'm aware of it)

What I do today is :

- on client side, I request a Facebook token (Facebook identification is a prerequisite)
- I send this token to my server, which uses it to retrieve a profile and so on.
- then the lifecycle of the application consists of a series of RESTful calls to my server.

Of course this is completely unsafe, and I was wondering how I could secure the whole thing:

1)  the initial token handshake.

2) all subsequent calls : now if you know the server URL you can easily forge RESTful calls

For 2) I was thinking about hashing some stuff with a key obtained during 1), but this is quite lame ... any ideas ?

Thanks :)

Comment: lots of articles and tutorials regarding this topic. Question is too broad for here

Comment: goto https://www.owasp.org and check out their projects. I especially recommend ASVS :)

Comment: You can ask on security.stackexchange.com